# How to stop Laravel from inserting data into database on page refresh?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am creating a project in Laravel. In `updatepackage.blade.php` a user checked a checkbox. The checkbox row values are then stored into database and sent to another view called `printpackage.blade.php`.
Here the problem starts. When the user refreshes the page, values shown in  entries are automatically inserted into database. I don't know how to stop this.

**updatepackage.blade.php**

```
<td align='center'>{{$i}}</td>      
<td><input type='text' name="meter[]" readonly value="{{$item['passmts']}}" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name="points[]" readonly value="{{$item['points']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name="pts[]" readonly value="{{$item['pts']}}"></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="ids[]"value="{{$i}}" /></td>
```

**clientcontroller.php**

```
 $insert=DB::table('packageroll')->insert(array(Input::all()));
 $tc=\Input::get('tc');
 $construction=\Input::get(construction');
 $table1= DB::table('packageroll')->where('tc','=',$tc)->where('construction','=',$construction)->get();
 return \View::make('dashboard.vendor.printpackage')->with('table1',$table1);
```

**printpackage.blade.php**

```
<td><input type='text' name='meter[]' value="{{$item['meter']}}" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='points[]' value="{{$item['points']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='pts[]'  value="{{$item['pts']}}"></td>
```

Comment: Can you provide more clearer information as like controller with action names, routes and the form which holds the checkboxes as current information is not sufficient to answer as of now only suggestion is comment this line `$insert=DB::table('packageroll')->insert(array(Input::all()));`

Comment: you need to separate your logic, one function for the view and one for the saving of the data, you redirect the page from the saveing of the data to the view

Comment: @alankar , in my first view hold the chckbox, action name is "updatepackage" and controller is storing the post data to database and sends data to another view  called "printpackage" in that view user needs to be print the dat , here also get values from the user

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use different validation for **store**  and **update** carefull if you have unique value  below i have mention how to handle

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, ['code'=>'required|unique:consignees,''=>'',''=>'']);
    }

public function update(Consignee $consignee,Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,['code'=>'required|unique:consignees,code,'.$consignee->id,''=>'',''=>'']);

    }
```